# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream not behaving asynchronously

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

In a Windows-8 program, I am calling HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream as follows,
where httpConnection has been previously set:

```
private System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpConnection;
public System.IO.Stream OutputStream 
{
    get 
    {
        lock(syncobj) 
        {
            httpConnection.BeginGetRequestStream
                (new AsyncCallback(getRequestResultCallback), null);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs without issue on Windows Phone 7. Due to some synchronization issues
I don't need to discuss here, I'm expecting (requiring) the code executing BeginGetRequestStream, and the code executing getRequestResultCallback to be on 
different threads. I thought that since getRequestResultCallback is run via the 
AsyncCallback, that this would be the case. It is in Windows 7, but not always
in Windows 8. Below, I have added a stack trace that shows a run where
BeginGetRequestStream and getRequestResultCallback were running on the same thread.

I'd appreciate any help understanding this issue.

Thanks in advance,
John Emerson

```
ua-desktop.exe!com.webalo.up.ua.wp.net.WpUaHttpRequest.getRequestResultCallback(System.IAsyncResult result) Line 120    C#
System.dll!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(System.IntPtr userToken) + 0x65 bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CaptureOrComplete(ref System.Threading.ExecutionContext cachedContext, bool returnContext) + 0x81 bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.FinishPostingAsyncOp() + 0x24 bytes    
System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) + 0x289 bytes   
ua-desktop.exe!com.webalo.up.ua.wp.net.WpUaHttpRequest.OutputStream.get() Line 31 + 0x37 bytes  C#
...
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() + 0x49 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() + 0x32 bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) + 0x15 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot) + 0xca bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) + 0xb3 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x7 bytes 
...
```